# How does one use inheritance when we have a template class have template pointer

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

How does one use inheritance when we have a template class have template pointer

We know that base class pointer can easily point to a derived class object . I created  another  template class and passed base and derived in it . However even with an overloaded = operator i cant make then equal which is my need .

Please take a look at [my sample code](http://ideone.com/eV4cdm) as it explains clearly the situation.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class base1
{
    public:
        int a;
        virtual int reset(){
            a=0;
            return a;
        }
};

class derived1: public base1
{
    public:
        int b;
        int reset(){
            b=0;
            return b;
        }

};

template <class T>
class templateClass{
public:
T *P;

    T& operator = (templateClass &b )
    {
        this.p = reinterpret_cast<T>(b.p);
        return *this;
    }

    void resetMyself(){
        P->reset();
    }
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    templateClass<base1> *p = new templateClass<base1> () ;
    templateClass<derived1> *q = new templateClass<derived1>() ;
    p=q;

    p->resetMyself();

    return 0;
}
```

When i compile my code i get

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:44:3: error: cannot convert ‘templateClass<derived1>*’ to ‘templateClass<base1>*’ in assignment
  p=q;
   ^
```

Comment: You cannot assign a pointer of type `templateClass<base1>` to a pointer of type `templateClass<derived1>`. You can, however, use templated functions (NOT templated (pure) virtual functions) and avoid the use of a templated base class. Don't know if that's viable in your case.

Comment: Ah, this is CRTP. A more direct explanation is that you cannot use something designed for static polymorphism (CRTP), and then get the associated benefits of dynamic polymorphism (inheritance). Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that in the first case, the types are determined at compile-time. In the second time, the types are determined during run-time. So the two are (in many scenarios) incompatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`templateClass<derived1>` and `templateClass<base1>` are as different as `int` and `double`. You can't assign a pointer to one to a pointer to the other.

You can, however, make `templateClass<derived1>` assignable to `templateClass<base1>` with a custom templated assignment operator:

```
template <class T>
class templateClass{
public:
    T *P;

    template <class U>
    templateClass& operator = (const templateClass<U> &b )
    {
        P = b.P;
        return *this;
    }

    void resetMyself(){
        P->reset();
    }
};
```

Then you can do something like ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/763dfd6978cdd059)):

```
templateClass<base1> p;
templateClass<derived1> q;
p = q;
```

Note that your original assignment operator's signature is incorrect. Also, `reinterpret_cast` is a terrible idea for this. To perform a pointer-to-base to pointer-to-derived conversion, use `static_cast`. The above version uses no cast and so allows implicit conversions only (i.e., from `derived` to `base` but not the other way around).